# How can I change this functional javascript for canvas app to object oriented one?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am a newbie on programming, and now working on a project about building a painting app with html 5 canvas.

There is a few functions that I want to add into my current painting app:

1. Text Inserting Feature like [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/VWzTL/):

   **sample code are as follows:**

   ```js
   var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
   font = '14px sans-serif',
   hasInput = false;

   canvas.onclick = function(e) {
   if (hasInput) return;
   addInput(e.clientX, e.clientY);
   }

   function addInput(x, y) {

   var input = document.createElement('input');

   input.type = 'text';
   input.style.position = 'fixed';
   input.style.left = (x - 4) + 'px';
   input.style.top = (y - 4) + 'px';

   input.onkeydown = handleEnter;

   document.body.appendChild(input);

   input.focus();

   hasInput = true;
   }
   ```

---

2. Image Filter function like [this one](https://www.viget.com/articles/instagram-style-filters-in-html5-canvas/):

   **sample code are as follows:**

   ```html
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
   <script>
   var photo  = new Image();
   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
   var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

   function render () {
   // Scale so that the image fills the container
   var width  = window.innerWidth;
   var scale  = width / photo.naturalWidth;
   var height = photo.naturalHeight * scale;;

   canvas.width  = width;
   canvas.height = height;
   ctx.drawImage(photo, 0, 0);}

   </script>
   ```

---

Nevertheless, my main html and other JS files created by my partner are using the object-oriented JavaScript syntax, which I have no idea how can I merge these functional JS with them.

**sample code are as follows:**

```js
class AddText extends PaintFunction {
constructor(contextReal, contextDraft) {
super();
this.contextReal = contextReal;
this.contextDraft = contextDraft;
```

---

**Here are the advice I am looking for:**

1. What is the logic of using object-oriented JS & functional JS?
2. How can I change the syntax between this 2 types of JS?
3. What is the logic/ thinking process when I want to use the syntax of constructor/ this ? I usually have confusion how to call the class in html & use the function shared in the common.js file.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I think you should do some more research and reading up on these topics rather than asking this type of question here.

Comment: Yes, it's truly confusing, if you are new for software development. Unfortunately, JS6 is very different (but much better) from old js. You need to understand how to use JS6, and how to work with module-based project, with imports. Start from here - http://es6-features.org/

Comment: Now, you should create `class YourClass {doLogic(){...}}` and put your code into `doLogic` function. Also, you should export your class from module to use inside of other JS modules.

Comment: @degr Hi degr, yes, I am completely new to this. I have actually read quite a lot of explanation stuff from MDN, w3schools, but still kind of difficult for me to understand the logic. Thanks for the reference!